# modifying a structure created with Add-Type

Tags: powershell

Whenever I make a modification to a structure I have created I have to exit from the session before the changes take place. Is there an better way to do this?

```
Add-Type @"
  public struct Computer {
  public string Name;
  public string ProductName;
  public string InstallDate;
  public string LastBootTime;
  public string ServicePack;
  public string ProductVersion;
  public string OSArchitecture;
  public string Manufacturer;
  public string Model;
  public string Memory;
}
"@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a .NET restriction.
For what I kwow, ona assembly loaded in an `appDomain` can't be unloaded.
That's why you have to close powershell console and restart a nes session.